# Crystal Report and Dataset

Tags: c#, database, crystal-reports, report

I am trying to add a crystal report into VS 2015, connected to a DataSet.
I managed to add the reportViewer to a form, create a DataSet with my SQL database, configured the report viewer using the wizard as to take the "clients" table from the DataSet (DataSet contains multiple tables), but when I run the application, I only get the column names and no data, whilst there are at least 20 clients in the database.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a connection to your datasource? If not you can do that via odbc.then in your designer see if you can load the data.before even running your app.

Comment: If he needs a datasource for the report without actually connecting to one, there is a way to do it in the Visual Studio project by creating a DataSet object and defining a DataTable with the same schema as the in memory DataSet/DataTable he is using to send data to the Crystal Report.  It's not ideal for editing reports in the designer, but it works well enough.  I've used this method often when importing CSV files as a DataSource that do not need to be imported into my database.